# Вопрос о стиле геттеров/сеттеров в C++ (и не только C++)

Tags: соглашения, c++

Что предпочитает уважаемое сообщество, и как аргументирует свои предпочтения:

Традиционный вариант:

```
class TFoo
{
    int value;
public:
    int GetValue() { return value; }
    void SetValue(int v) { value = v; }
};
```

Более наглядный (?) вариант:

```
class TFoo
{
    int value;
public:
    int ValueGet() { return value; }
    void ValueSet(int v) { value = v; }
};
```

Comment: Смысл подобных вопросов - понять, как писать предельно очевидный и наглядный код, не вызывающий лишних вопросов (и отвращения).

Comment: У каждого свои предпочтения и он от них вряд ли отступит. За исключением тех случаев, когда правило именования регламентировано корпоративными соглашениями. Так что подобные вопросы - толчение воды в ступе.

Comment: Я так понимаю, что дело не в том, чтобы кого-то заставить как-то писать, а самому писать так, чтобы другие могли читать без судорог :)

Answer (score 2):

Более наглядный вариант (ИМХО) в стиле *глагол обозначающий действие*, затем *существительное, на которое это действие направлено*. Т.е. getValue() и setValue().

Попробуйте "на вкус" два словосочетания: *получить значение* и *значение получить*. Первое звучит более естественно.

Comment: Второе звучит более логично: сначала объявляется сущность, затем - выполняемые с ней манипуляции.
Вообще, правила, очевидные для естественных языков, вряд ли применимы здесь.
Поэтому я и задал вопрос.

Comment: Программный код читает все равно человек, и (может и бессознательно) применяет к нему привычные правила естественных языков. Но опять же, это мое ИМХО.  
Я согласен с IAZ о личных предпочтениях, пока что не создали Единого свода правил оформления кода для всех языков :)

Comment: @Equinox тем не менее, для многих языков правила создали. И это правильно.

Comment: @kirelagin скорее уж не для языков (хотя и для некоторых есть такое), а скорее для библиотек и технологий типа COM в котором свойства реализуются добавкой "get_" и "put_" для переменной. А правильно это или нет - время покажет, а пока все будут пользоваться чем захотят :)

Answer (score -2):

По возможности вообще нужно избегать геттеров и сеттеров. Аргументы:

1. Сеттер и геттер - по сути тоже самое, что и обращение к членам класса, только более уродливый способ этого.
2. Для конструирования объекта с определенными свойствами используйте конструкторы со списками инициализации. И перегрузку конструкторов по типам аргументов.
3. Нужно проектировать классы, так чтобы их ф-ции-члены выполняли осмысленные действия. И умельчать их до уровня сеттеров-геттеров, наверняка, не нужно.

Плюс у геттеров и сеттеров только один - при их тотальном использовании есть возможность протоколировать обращения к переменным. Т.е. возможно, что отладка станет проще. Но, учитывая, что все равно остается возможность обращения к переменным напрямую, то будет появляться соблазн использовать то один способ, то другой.

Касательно вопроса "что лучше?"

Мне кажется, что лучше вариант getValue/setValue, чем любой другой (get_/put_, ValueGet/ValueSet и пр.). А еще лучше отказаться от get/set и обзывать accessor'ы по названию данных. Например, так:

```
class my
{
   private:
     int size_;
   ...
   public:
     int size(void) {return size_;}
     void size(int s) {size_ = s;}//хотя зачем? тут еще должна быть куча логики
     // так что лучше ввести ф-цию resize(int) ;)
   ...
}
```

PS: и еще бесят названия классов (типов) с буквы T. Почему? См. [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/7481/%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%8F-stop-the-cclass-idiotism)

PPS: еще нашел интересный вариант именования у [Qt](http://doc.trolltech.com/qq/qq13-apis.html#theartofnaming):

Comment: Ответ на 1 - сеттеры и геттеры не являются "более уродливыми" способами обращения к членам класса, а защищают члены класса от установки их в неверные/непредусмотренные/ошибочные значения - установив член класса как private, создав для него геттер и сеттер с проверкой на валидность устанавливаемого значения можно гарантировать себе и программе отсутствие ошибок времени выполнения связанных с неверными переданными данными.

Comment: ОКей. Сделайте класс декартовой точки. С сеттером и геттером. А я покажу, что это некорректно.
<i>программе отсутствие ошибок времени выполнения связанных с неверными переданными данными.</i><p>
Это провокация, т.к. легко можно setter'ом перевести объект в некорректное состояние, если корректность значений пары (или более) переменных членов класса имеет какую-то хитрую зависимость. Тока не надо рассказывать, что будете использовать сеттер вида struct _x{int a; int b}; setStructBlaBlaBla(struct _x x); - не поверю.<p>
К тому же геттер следует делать const'ным и inline'овым.

Comment: А еще если необходимо сделать что-то в духе числа int, лежащего в определенном диапазоне, то удобно использовать соответствующий шаблон.