# Статья "Stop the CClass idiotism"

Tags: c++

Несколько лет назад читал статью с таким (примерно) названием. Тема: не прекращается дебильная практика начинать имена классов с "C" (В TP/Delphi с "T"). Автор - вероятно американец сербского происхождения. Гугл не помогает (может буквы совсем не те набираю).
Помогите, кто встречал (знает) найти.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Думаю, Вы имеете в виду вот эту статью: [Dejan Jelovic. CStupidClassName](http://www.jelovic.com/articles/stupid_naming.htm)

Comment: Да именно эту. Спасибо